# Prove that $n$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Establish the following test for primes.

If $n$ is odd, greater than $5$, and there 
exist relatively prime integers $a$ and $b$ such that 
$a — b = n$ and $a + b = p_1\cdot p_2\cdot... p_k$ 
(where $p_1, p_2 , . . . , p_k$ are the odd primes less than $\sqrt n$ ), then $n$ is prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose $p_1|n$, then $p_1|(a+b)+(a-b)=2a$ and $p_1|(a+b)-(a-b)=2b$. What can you do using $p_1$ is odd, and what can you do with all other $p_i$s?

Comment: cool hint, thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

$a + b = \prod p_i$

$a - b = \prod p_i - 2b = n$.  gcd($a,b$) =1 so none of the $p_i$ divide $\prod p_i - 2b = n$ (except maybe 2 but n is odd so that's not possible).  But the $p_i$ are all the primes up to the $\sqrt(n)$.  So as none of those primes divide n, n is prime.